# Video upload and stream

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, video

What is the best way (which consumes less memory, fast upload and fast stream) I can upload and show a video in asp.net ?

Is there any free web video player available which I can use to show videos on site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) to play videos on my ASP.NET site,

I call the video using a custom handler (.ashx) and the following code in the handler

```
context.Response.Buffer = true;
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1));
context.Response.ContentType = "video/x-flv";
context.Response.TransmitFile(<Location of file>);
```

the above is based on a Switch/Case statement depending on file extension.